# How to restart the code after a loop

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Testing { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        while(i>=0){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number:");        
        i = input.nextInt();

            for(;i>0;i--){

                for (j=i; j>0; j--){

                 System.out.print("*");
                 }
                 System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

is the code, after I input the number and it prints the result, it should ask me if I want to try again or exit as choice 1.again 2.exit, I'm not sure how to make the code restart from the beginning. Any help would be good.

Comment: It seems you know how to handle loops. So, why do you not use another loop to do so?

Comment: Use loop and `switch` or `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the switch case to do that like

```
 String choice;
        switch (choose) {
            case 1:  choice = "start again ";
                     break;
            case 2:  choice = "exit";
                     break;

            default: choice = "Invalid match";
                     break;
        }
```

and based on the value of choice you can run your loop

Answer (score 1):

To represent the behavior you're asking for (since you don't want to ask the user to continue the first time), I would suggest using a `do {} while;` loop as such:

```
int redo = 0;
do {
    //Initialize your variables
    //Read the Input
    //Process the Input

    System.out.println("Enter 1 to do it again:");
    redo = input.nextInt();
} while(redo == 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Enclose everything in another loop. This way you can 'restart it' from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

When you need a loop, use a loop.
If you need two nested loops, then use 2 nested loops.

A psuedo-code like example:

```
loopy
{
  ask for input

  loopy
  {
      process input
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop. Enclose what you want to 'restart' from the beginning in a while loop.

As condition of the loop, use a boolean value that you update once you want to break the loop and close the program. E.g.: when the user presses a key, your loop will end.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
while(true){
      //get input
    for(){
        //process output
    }
    //get input for continue or exit
    if(input is exit){
        //break out of while loop
    }
}
```

Comment: This structure is simpler if you use a `do {} while;` statement instead.

Comment: You're right.  Your solution above is cleaner and simpler for an already established programmer.  I just provided an alternative that may or may not be easier for the OP to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {

//get user input
if (input==2){
System.exit(1);
}
//
else{
System.out.print(input);
}
//
} while(!done);
```

You just need to put your existing code into another loop, and then you can set the condition for when exit is desired to a number of different exit methods.

```
System.exit(1);
done=false;
```